# How can I combine a line of code with the data.frame() function?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've written a line of code to calculate GDP change over a decade. I want this to appear in the published report. However, it appears without titles - specifically, **Country** and **Value**.

This is the code I've written:

```
#code for GDP growth 1960 to 1970
round(with(Belize_1960_1970, (Value[Year == 1970] - Value[Year == 1960])/Value[Year == 1960])*100)
```

In this case, the output was 90.

To improve the published 'look', I used the data frame function, as it would allow me to include **Country** and **GDP_percent**

```
country <- "Belize"
GDP_percent <- 90
df <- data.frame(country, GDP_percent)
print(df, row.names=FALSE)
```

I then hid the code and output which I had used to calculate the change in GDP, leaving the data frame with its labelled information. As a workaround, it functions well.

However, is there a neater solution which would combine the data.frame() function with the line of code I used to calculate the change in GDP?

My solution was very clunky:

```
#code for GDP growth 1960 to 1970
data.frame(round(with(Belize_1960_1970, (Value[Year == 1970] - Value[Year == 1960])/Value[Year == 1960])*100))
```

Comment: Short answer, yes, there are likely some needless steps here and it can all be done relatively simply then displayed in a way that you need - can you please provide a reproducible example so we can see the format of the `Belize_1960_19701 object?

Comment: Please give us some dummy or sample data to work with. What you are asking is possible, but we need some data to play with. @PaulStaffordAllen has rightly asked for a reprex.

Comment: This is the data which I was using. Unfortunately, I didn't use the formatting for tables when I was writing out my questions. I couldn't see it when I came back to add this comment. It may be of some use. Thank you for your interest in my question.                                                                                                                             -1960 28071888.5622 -1961 29964370.7126 -1962 31856922.8615 -1963 33749405.0119 -1964 36193826.1235 -1965 40069930.0699 -1966 44405594.4056 -1967 47379310.3448 -1968 44910179.6407 -1969 47305389.2216 -1970 53233532.9341

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as suggested by the others, it would be useful to have a reproducible example.
To get you started I downloaded the GDP data from https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/gross-domestic-product?tab=chart&country=BLZ.
Your data might look different. But you should be able to plug your example in the code below.

What we understand is that you are dealing with 2 problems:

- calculating the GDP change in a "neater" way
- presenting it as a table

**Problem 1: data frame operation (not necessarily calculating for one year only)**

```
library(readr)      # read support for tabular data
library(dplyr)      # data crunching

# read in source data ------------
gdp <- read_csv("gross-domestic-product.csv")   # csv downloaded from ourworldindata
```

This is what our data file looks like:

```
gdp
# A tibble: 10,457 × 4
   Entity      Code   Year `GDP (constant 2015 US$)`
   <chr>       <chr> <dbl>                     <dbl>
 1 Afghanistan AFG    2002                7228792320
 2 Afghanistan AFG    2003                7867259392
 3 Afghanistan AFG    2004                7978511360
 4 Afghanistan AFG    2005                8874475520
 5 Afghanistan AFG    2006                9349916672
 6 Afghanistan AFG    2007               10642666496
  ... [truncated for presentation purposes]
```

GDP is given in 2015 USD - this might be different from your data.
The variable name is a bit long. Thus, let's rename it.

I assume you may want to calculate the percentage change across multiple years (decades) and possibly countries.
Thus, let's add the respective "10 year earlier results into the table".

Note: we filter for `Belize` - which was in your question. If we do not apply the filter you may want to `group_by(Entity)` to operate over the given countries.

```
blz <- gdp %>% 
     filter(Entity == "Belize") %>%                 # filter for Belize
     rename(GDP = `GDP (constant 2015 US$)`) %>%    # rename GDP column
     mutate(Year2 = lag(Year, 10)                   # optional: 10 years ago
            ,GDP2 = lag(GDP,  10)                   # GDP 10 years ago
     #-------------------- calculate percentage change and round it
            ,CHANGE_PERC = ( (GDP - GDP2) / GDP2 ) *100 %>% round(digits = 2)
    ) %>% 
    tail()   # show results at the end ~ recent years in the data set
```

This yields:

```
  Entity Code   Year        GDP Year2       GDP2 CHANGE_PERC
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1 Belize BLZ    2015 1721700992  2005 1354744960       27.1 
2 Belize BLZ    2016 1721128832  2006 1420117888       21.2 
3 Belize BLZ    2017 1752344576  2007 1427374848       22.8 
4 Belize BLZ    2018 1803268992  2008 1477187456       22.1 
5 Belize BLZ    2019 1835056896  2009 1480399744       24.0 
6 Belize BLZ    2020 1577955712  2010 1524864000        3.48
```

Note: As we use `lag(xxx, 10)`, there will be years that do not have a value for an earlier year/GDP. This will result in an NA. You can filter on this.

**Problem 2: printing as table**

You mention you include this in a document. Thus, it is fair to assume you are using Rmarkdown for this.
Rmarkdown supports different table packages, e.g. you print a table with `knitr::kable()` or other packages like `{flextable}`, `{gt}`, etc.

Simply include the call to the object into a Rmarkdown chunk, i.e. `{r} knitr::kable(blz)` or

```
library(flextable)
flextable(blz)
```

The flextable will look as follows:

[image: flextable example of table output]

If you only want to print a specific year, use `blz %>% filter(Year == 2017)` as part of your table call.

Obviously, you can also change the table header / column names as you like / prefer.

In closing, if you use Rmarkdown, you can also embed the values in your document "inline". E.g. you can create a single-year-object, `blz_2017 <- blz %>% filter(Year == 2017)`.

In your text you can now write an "inline chunk" refering to the object and its variables. E.g. The GDP change from `r blz_2017$Year2` to `r blz_2017$Year` was `r blz_2017$GDP_CHANGE` %. The inline chunk will print the variable when you render the document.

Comment: Thankyou @Ray. I had come across lag() but I did not how to use it. Your use of it answered my question perfectly.